# issues with KML link to Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to resolve an issue with uploading a live kml file to the google maps api. I have a live website that I uploaded the kml file to, but when I use the url within the call function it doesn't show up in the google maps api. It's a public kml file....the website that I'm trying to use the google maps api is not live, just run off my desktop at the moment.

any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? The website kml link is: http://www.gsphotoalchemy.com/170113.kml

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.gsphotoalchemy.com/170113.kml'
    });
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

I can post the full html code if needed, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

your KML file is too big, see the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) for size and complexity limitations:

[feedvalidator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gsphotoalchemy.com%2F170113.kml)

If you do something like this in your code to check the status of the KmlLayer:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, "status_changed", function() {
   document.getElementById('kmlstatus').innerHTML = "Kml Status:"+kmlLayer.getStatus();
 });
```

you will get:

```
Kml Status:DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.gsphotoalchemy.com/170113.kml)

Comment: +1 this is the exact answer. I wonder why O.P. leave a question and never check back for the answer.